# Excel: String within String lookup

Tags: excel

I have a long list of addresses, example:

```
grundisburgh woodbridge suffolk uk
```

How can I match it with a city, from a list? In this case city is Woodbridge
Conceptually it is something like vlookup with wild characters, but unsure on how to this.

I tried different array formulas, but none produce desired effect.

I was able to say if it is in the list with:

```
{=COUNTIF(C2,"*"&Cities!C:C&"*")}
```

Where `C2` is the address field, and `Cities!C:C` is the list of Cities

Cities and address are both lowered, to reduce any issues with case sensitivity

Comment: Is it not possible for you to 'Text to Columns' your addresses string using space as a delimiter, then just match on the resulting array?

Comment: I think you have the criteria backwards.  Try: `=COUNTIF($Cities!C:C,"*" &C2&"*")`

Comment: @TVOHM no, there also multie word cities so it would create different lengths.

Comment: @ScottCraner I dont think so, `C2` has the address and cities is what we are looking for

Comment: Do you want to **count** the number of matching records or **locate** the first record??

Answer (score 1):

Try this array formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(C2,"* "&Cities!C:C&" *"))
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Also the cities must be spelled and capitalized exactly the same in the two lists, so make sure account for every option.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I tried this and got a return of 1048574 for each test value I entered.

Comment: Do you realize that the formula in your picture is different than the formula in your answer in structure (not just cell reference)?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman No only the cell references have changed.  C2 for A1 and Cities!C:C for F1:F3.  See the comments as to why it is this way.

Comment: Perhaps I could have been more explicit in my previous comment and used more precise language. I think the row references are important for this to work correctly. In other words, I think `Cities!C:C` does **not** work, but `Cities!C1:C3` does work. At least in my testing.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes I missed that it would do that.  I will add something to the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102020/discussion-between-scott-holtzman-and-scott-craner).

Answer (score 1):

This **array** formula worked for me, but it requires you send the beginning and start rows.

```
=FIND(Cities!C1:C3,C1)
```

You can also extract which city is in the row by this **regular** formula:

```
=MID(C1,D1,FIND(" ",C1,D1+1)-D1) *where D1 is the cell that holds the above array formula.
```